# jam0.exe stopped when bootstrapping

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I am trying to use Boots library 1.46.1. I use command prompt of Visula Studio 2010. I download boost package, create on C:/ folder Boost where i unzip package, change dir in command prompt and try to bootstrap. And I got message jam0.exe crushes. What can be a problem and how to solve it?

Regards 
ewa

Comment: Do you get some more output to the console window?

Comment: No, there only appears message error. When you go into details there is something like this: (but it is in Polish so I dont know if you know what is going on here) Podpis problemu: Nazwa zdarzenia problemu: APPCRASH Nazwa aplikacji: jam0.exe Wersja aplikacji: 0.0.0.0 Sygnatura czasowa aplikacji: 525ed38f Nazwa modułu z błędem: bitguard.dll Wersja modułu z błędem: 2.6.1694.246 Sygnatura czasowa modułu z błędem: 524a99fc Kod wyjątku: c0000005

Comment: Przesunięcie wyjątku: 0017966f Wersja systemu operacyjnego: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 Identyfikator ustawień regionalnych: 1045 Dodatkowe informacje 1: 0a9e Dodatkowe informacje 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 Dodatkowe informacje 3: 0a9e Dodatkowe informacje 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

and the command prompt just stop working.

Comment: Oh, it crashes with "access violation". Do you bootstrap it for 64bit architecture (i.e. use VS2012 x64 command prompt)?

Comment: the problem is even deeper than I was supposed to be. I wanted to install VS2012 x64, the default folder for VS2012 was PorogramFiles x86. The access to installation was denied. I went to the folder and tried to make an empty folder but the access to create was denided. Then I wanted to change User Account Control Settings and after clicking on it nothing happen (there should be dialog box). What is going on my computer ? These can cause the problem with boost and solve other problems that I have met. Help!

Comment: Log in to administrator account and google how to disable UAC. Besides, always run command prompts with elevated privileges ("as administrator..."). But I'm afraid all these won't solve your original problem, as older Boost.Build versions used to have some issue with [x64 platform](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/05/203657.php). So, if elevating permissions doesn't help, try building the lasted Boost version.

Comment: I have the same issue with VS2012. I open a command line window and try to run .\bootstrap.bat and get the `jam0.exe` stopped working `C:\boost\boost_1_51_0>.\bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.`

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender has flagged jam0.exe as trojan for a while.  You will have to add it to the allowed threats list in Windows Defender.